# JSON is undefined error when using latest jquery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Please refer below html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

when am opening this html page in IE7 browser it throws error like " **JSON" undefined** and if am opening same in IE8 browser means it throws error like " **Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'**

how can i resolve this issue ?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery 2 does not support IE 8 and older. If you want to support those browsers, use the (still supported) jQuery 1.x branch.

— http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Jquery 1.9 version** only for `IE 6,7,8` Jquery 2.0 not supported in `older versions` of `IE`

`As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers. In return it is smaller, faster, and can be used in JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility often causes problems of its own.` **But don’t worry, the jQuery team still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8**. `You can (and should) continue to use jQuery 1.9 (and the upcoming 1.10) on web sites that need to accommodate older browsers.`

Read [jquery-2-0-released](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)